# Replacing part of string in R to turn into a numerical value

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataframe which contains a column with condensed numeric values.

```
final_table.df                      ##Dataframe
final_table.df$insta_followers      ##Column
```

it contains two sets of formatted values that I need to change:

1.) A value such as 10K where I can replace the "K" to make 000

2.) **A value which I can't solve such as 9.3K, which I need to become 9300**

How do I replace the values such as 9.3K to become 9300 in my rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the K from the vectors and turn it into a numeric variable

```
x<-c("9.3K","10K")
substring(x,1,nchar(x)-1) # removes the last character "9.3" "10"
as.numeric(substring(x,1,nchar(x)-1))*1000 # turn into a numeric and multiply by 1000
9300 10000
```

If you have values that do not contain a `K` for example `92` then you could work in an `ifelse` commmand something like

```
as.numeric(ifelse(grepl("K",x),as.numeric(substring(x,1,nchar(x)-1))*1000 ,x))
```

If `x` contains `K` convert in the manner described above otherwise return `x`

Answer (score 0):

Using "strsplit" you can solve this problem. Here an example

```
x = "9.3K"
y = strsplit(x,"[.]") #gives y[[1]][1] = "9" and y[[1]][2] = "3K"
k = as.numeric(y[[1]][1]) #convert string to float
d = strsplit(y[[1]][2],"") #gives d[[1]][1]="3" and d[[1]][2]="K"
d1 = as.numeric(d[[1]][1])
number = k*1000 + d1*100
```

I hope this will work, if not inform me!

Answer (score 0):

I got started on about three different solutions but I think this is the most clean, simple, and understandable. Can expand if you have more formats than just 1 & 2 but it should work fine for those.

```
df$followers <- ifelse(substr(df$followers, 2, 2)==".",  # if second char is "."
                       gsub("K", "00", df$followers),  # replace K with 00
                       gsub("K", "000", df$followers))  # else replace K with 000
df$followers <- as.numeric(df$followers)  # convert to numeric at the end
```